# signature in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to use a signature input in React Native. After installing the library, the signature area refuses to appear. Even I'am using the same code as in the documentation, but nothing happens the signature area refuses to appear.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import SignatureScreen from 'react-native-signature-canvas';

export default function Signature({
  onChange,
  value,
  placeholder,
  text,
  onOK,
}) {
  const ref = useRef();

  const handleOK = (signature) => {
    console.log(signature);
    onOK(signature);
  };

  const handleEmpty = () => {
    console.log('Empty');
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    console.log('clear success!');
  };
  const handleEnd = () => {
    ref.current.readSignature();
  };
  const handleData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Text>test</Text>
      <SignatureScreen
        ref={ref}
        onEnd={handleEnd}
        onOK={handleOK}
        onEmpty={handleEmpty}
        onClear={handleClear}
        onGetData={handleData}
        autoClear={true}
        descriptionText={text}
      />
      <Text>test</Text>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post your codes as images!

Comment: have you tried using the `<View>` tag instead of a fragment tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to set manually size before your `<SignatureScreen />` and inside as well?

```
<View style={{width: 400, height: 400, backgroundColor: "tomato"}}>
  ...
</View>
```

Sometime the component is present but does not display correctly —it happens to me all the time with `<Image />`